# Is this.setState({}) guaranteed to cause a re-render

Tags: reactjs

I inherited some code to maintain, with this line in it:

```
this.setState({}); // Force update
```

Is this guaranteed to cause a re-render?

Comment: A forced re-render would be guaranteed with `this.forceUpdate()` but questions the code structure and practices.

Comment: Thanks - but will this.setState({}) force an update?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`setState` merges the object passed as argument into the actual state in an immutable way. `this.setState({})` will merge nothing to state but will actually return a new object, the shallow comparison performed by `React` will always assert to `false` and a re render will be triggered, unless explicitly cancelled with `shouldComponentUpdate`. So yes, in this case it is equivalent to `forceUpdate` and it comes with the same [caveats](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#forceupdate).

Answer (score 3):

You can actually [test it](https://snack.expo.io/@remeus/force-re-render) easily:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button } from 'react-native';

class Test extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log('render');
    return <Button onPress={() => this.setState({})} title='Test' />;
  }
}

export default Test;
```

Every time the button is clicked, the console.log triggers.

An interesting point is that if you replace `this.setState({})` by `this.setState()`, there is no re-render after a click.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation it is and several other methods in order

1. static getDerivedStateFromProps()
2. shouldComponentUpdate()
3. render()
4. getSnapshotBeforeUpdate()
5. componentDidUpdate()

please see this [link](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#updating) for detailed

Answer (score -1):

It depends. If you want to render a component, react internally checks is DOM equals with previous(this occurs if props of component is not changed at all). If dom equals with previous version, react checks `shouldComponentUpdate`. `forceUpdate` is different than `this.setState({})`, which always render components.

Comment: This contradicts the answers and documentation referenced in them